# Getting Error while calling openfire service for httpbind

Tags: xml, openfire

I'm trying to call login using below code for login using openfire but getting service unavailable error,

I'm running this code for calling login on openfire

```
<body rid='3831379072' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='server' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```

`http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind` (while running this url 404 not found error getting and I'm calling that direct url)

What is the problem occurred, is that service has stopped from server or any other problem I don't know what's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using strophe.js then use new `Strophe.Connection()` object with parameter in the form of `http://{localhost-ip}:7070/http-bind/`.

I think you are trying  to connect `http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind` which is not valid connection to server it just a way of writing. You have to edit it.

Comment: Thanks for Reply Pooja, i m trying to call like this : var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://mysitename/http-bind/'); and also i have tried like this http://mysitename:7070/http-bind, but it doesnt work...